# Replace the Variable Price range by the chosen variation price in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-variations

On WooCommerce, I would like to change the Variable single product page layout. Because when you have an variable product you get this wired price rage (below product title) in the Variable Product page and it shows in the shop page as well.

For me, the standard way is to show the lowest price of the product in the shop as well as product page and change that price according to user selection of variables. I can't believe why.

I can remove the price range and show the lowest price using this code snippet.

https://businessbloomer.com/disable-variable-product-price-range-woocommerce/

But then again, that lowest price doesn't change according to select variables. There are again two prices in the variable product layout. This is my current variable product page layout

http://www.preorders.lk/product/beats-solo3-wireless-on-ear-headphones/

So, can anyone please help to remove the price range from the variable product page and show only one lowest price ( under the product title) of the product as default. So that price should be change according to the variables which that product have. And that lowest price should be show in the shop page as well.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 19):

### 2021 *definitive update*

> **Works for WooCommerce 4+ and 5+ available on:**
>
> *[Replace the Variable Price range by the chosen variation price in WooCommerce 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704727/replace-the-variable-price-range-by-the-chosen-variation-price-in-woocommerce-4/50707820#50707820)*

---

**Update *(December 2017)*:** to avoid, Problems regarding non variable products in some themes and a repetition availability bug in some themes

**Note:** Some plugins like the German Market or some themes **will not work** with this code, as they make their own changes in the hooks or in the html structure.

This is completely possible.

1. First we remove the unwanted price.
2. We output instead the variable price without the price range and show the lowest price.
3. We make a copy of this variable price in a hidden container (to be used/read by our jQuery script)
4. Then we hide the containers of chosen variation price (and the stock availability)
5. With the help of our **`jQuery`** script, when we get the chosen variation price, we replace the variable price (and display the stock availability).
6. If the customer change of variation we update the price... If the variation price is not displayed during that change process, our variable price is displayed

Here is that code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'move_variations_single_price', 1 );
function move_variations_single_price(){
    global $product, $post;

    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        // removing the variations price for variable products
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

        // Change location and inserting back the variations price
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_variation_single_price', 10 );
    }
}

function replace_variation_single_price(){
    global $product;

    // Main Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
    $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    // Sale Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
    sort( $prices );
    $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    if ( $price !== $saleprice && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</del> <ins>' . $price . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</ins>';
    }

    ?>
    <style>
        div.woocommerce-variation-price,
        div.woocommerce-variation-availability,
        div.hidden-variable-price {
            height: 0px !important;
            overflow:hidden;
            position:relative;
            line-height: 0px !important;
            font-size: 0% !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('select').blur( function(){
            if( '' != $('input.variation_id').val() ){
                if($('p.availability'))
                    $('p.availability').remove();
                $('p.price').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html()).append('<p class="availability">'+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+'</p>');
                console.log($('input.variation_id').val());
            } else {
                $('p.price').html($('div.hidden-variable-price').html());
                if($('p.availability'))
                    $('p.availability').remove();
                console.log('NULL');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php

    echo '<p class="price">'.$price.'</p>
    <div class="hidden-variable-price" >'.$price.'</div>';
}
```

*Code goes in any php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin php file.*

This code is tested and works on WooCommerce 3.2.x *(should work on WooCommerce 2.6.x too)*

> You can optionally move the CSS *(`<style></style>`)* to the `styles.css` file of your active child theme (or active theme) and then remove it from this function…

---

Related:

- [Move the variation price location in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618510/move-the-variation-price-location-in-woocommerce/47618953#47618953)

Comment: Thank you for very clear answer LoicTheAztec. I tried with your code. But this is what I got

Comment: Thank you for very clear answer LoicTheAztec. I tried with your code. But this is what I got

http://www.preorders.lk/product/beats-solo3-wireless-on-ear-headphones/

And shop page still shows the price range under the product. This is the way I want to have. 

http://prntscr.com/frs2zm

I only want to have one price which should under product title. Also, that one price should be it's lowest price if there is not discount. If there is a discount, that price is lower than normal lowest price that should be show as default in the product page as well as shop page.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I really appreciate it. I checked your link and that what I exactly want. I'm really sorry. I'm not an expert on PHP. Anyway, I added your code into my chid-theme function.php file. But then, layout got little confused. You can check it from here Loic. http://www.preorders.lk/product/beats-solo3-wireless-on-ear-headphones/
Also, when the product is not available, ( in this product Gloss Black ), it shows as undefined. You can see if you go to my link Loic. Again I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sure. I will do that now.

Comment: This is great, but is there a way to display the variation price when it is selected and the page is refreshed? When the page is refreshed, `tmpl-variation-template` automatically shows the price. I can't grab the html on document load because there is a slight delay.

Comment: Nice work @LoicTheAztec but its working in single product page only. how can we show single price in shop page too?

Comment: @Asher This is about Product variation selection which is only active in single product pages… So there is no way for this in Woocommerce archives pages as Shop…

Comment: It only works once, when you switch from first variation to different one. If you swtich back to the first variation, it doesn't refresh the price anymore. WooCommerce 3.4

Comment: @retroriff use this version instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704727/replace-price-range-handling-default-variation-displayed-price-in-woocommerce-3/50707820#50707820

Comment: @retroriff Sorry but it works on last woocommerce version… I have tested it. Now on some themes or with some plugins, changes are needed in the code.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec How can I chat with you? I have some question for you. I hope, I can connect with you. Thank so much.

Answer (score 13):

Late to the party but I was looking for a more dynamic/universal solution and less code so I adjusted the answer to the following.

The price is updated based on the [variation-form triggers](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.0.1/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.js#L30) so the styling and original HTML is maintained.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'move_variations_single_price', 1 );
function move_variations_single_price(){
  global $product, $post;
  if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_variation_single_price', 10 );
  }
}

function replace_variation_single_price() {
  ?>
    <style>
      .woocommerce-variation-price {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var priceselector = '.product p.price';
        var originalprice = $(priceselector).html();

        $( document ).on('show_variation', function() {
          $(priceselector).html($('.single_variation .woocommerce-variation-price').html());
        });
        $( document ).on('hide_variation', function() {
          $(priceselector).html(originalprice);
        });
      });
    </script>
  <?php
}
```

Successfully tested with v4.0.1. As long as themes/plugins don't change the markup it should work. If not you can easily change the `priceselector` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for this solution Luuk Skeur, it works great! 
Although I have a small issue. I am running on the Flatsometheme (if that makes any difference).

The issue is that when using your snippet then "<span class="price">" is added before the price. This is not there on simple products. The result is that both the price and the tax message is displayed too big. Is there a way to make sure that <span class="price"> is not added?


https://nimb.ws/vCfbU6

Comment: Hi @TobiasBindemo, good to hear! :) This snippet doesn't mess with the CSS or HTML in a way, it simply replaces the price with the WooCommerce generated *variation*-price. If you want to modify that then use some custom CSS or overwrite the template.

Comment: This is exactly what I looked for. Thank you!

Comment: Works on WooCommerce v6, you may need to change `woocommerce-variation-price` to `woocommerce-variation`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware that I am resurrecting an old thread here, but something I discovered when using this code is that you need to be aware that with this code as is you risk stopping single, non-variable prices from displaying on some themes as:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
```

is triggered on all product pages, regardless of it being a variable product or not.

You can use the below version which simply checks if the current product is variable or not before running the rest of the code.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'check_if_variable_first' );
function check_if_variable_first(){
    if ( is_product() ) {
        global $post;
        $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
        if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            // removing the price of variable products
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

// Change location of
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_wc_template_single_price', 10 );
function custom_wc_template_single_price(){
    global $product;

// Variable product only
if($product->is_type('variable')):

    // Main Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
    $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    // Sale Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
    sort( $prices );
    $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    if ( $price !== $saleprice && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</del> <ins>' . $price . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</ins>';
    }

    ?>
    <style>
        div.woocommerce-variation-price,
        div.woocommerce-variation-availability,
        div.hidden-variable-price {
            height: 0px !important;
            overflow:hidden;
            position:relative;
            line-height: 0px !important;
            font-size: 0% !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('select').blur( function(){
            if( '' != $('input.variation_id').val() ){
                $('p.price').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html()).append('<p class="availability">'+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+'</p>');
                console.log($('input.variation_id').val());
            } else {
                $('p.price').html($('div.hidden-variable-price').html());
                if($('p.availability'))
                    $('p.availability').remove();
                console.log('NULL');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php

    echo '<p class="price">'.$price.'</p>
    <div class="hidden-variable-price" >'.$price.'</div>';

endif;
}

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What should I use in order to display this on the archive or in a category loop too?