# Move Variation Price Above Add to Cart Button in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, price

I'm having problem with my WooCommerce site. I am actually trying to hide the total amount showing just above the Add to Cart Button after selecting all variations. I just want to keep it showing in the main Price section where it shows the product Price range.
Please assist me to get it sorted out.

Please see the attached snapshot and help me to get this sorted out.

[image: Snapshot Explaining exact thing that I want help for.]

Comment: You need to add more code, like the current page template or anything... we cannot guess how to help you without it...

Comment: Or [Move the variation price location in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47618953/3730754)