# Bug - duplication of the status "In stock" (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

The answer to this question - [Replace Variable Product Price by the chosen variation price in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912300/replace-variable-product-price-by-the-chosen-variation-price-in-woocommerce-3) - was the answer with the solution of the problem.

How do I fix this bug?

If the Variable product has the same price of variations, then `there is a duplication of the status "In stock"`, Like this:

[image]

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'check_if_variable_first' );
function check_if_variable_first(){
if ( is_product() ) {
    global $post;
    $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        // removing the price of variable products
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

// Change location of
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_wc_template_single_price', 10 );
function custom_wc_template_single_price(){
global $product;

// Variable product only
if($product->is_type('variable')):

// Main Price
$prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
$price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

// Sale Price
$prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
sort( $prices );
$saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

if ( $price !== $saleprice && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
    $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</del> <ins>' . $price . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</ins>';
}

?>
<style>
    div.woocommerce-variation-price,
    div.woocommerce-variation-availability,
    div.hidden-variable-price {
        height: 0px !important;
        overflow:hidden;
        position:relative;
        line-height: 0px !important;
        font-size: 0% !important;
    }
</style>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('select').blur( function(){
        if( '' != $('input.variation_id').val() ){
            $('p.price').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html()).append('<p class="availability">'+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+'</p>');
            console.log($('input.variation_id').val());
        } else {
            $('p.price').html($('div.hidden-variable-price').html());
            if($('p.availability'))
                $('p.availability').remove();
            console.log('NULL');
        }
    });
});
</script>
<?php

echo '<p class="price">'.$price.'</p>
<div class="hidden-variable-price" >'.$price.'</div>';

endif;
}

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It should be better to give a live link of a variable product, as your theme can customize the html structure and classes names…

Comment: http://fh7988px.bget.ru/?product=product-41

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answers and for finally wanting to help. And I'm not a bot. Yesterday I showed a link in which you can see the error about which I wrote in the first message. Today, I replaced the code with the one you proposed in the answer yesterday. The error has not been fixed.

Comment: http://fh7988px.bget.ru/?product=product-41

Comment: The structure of your html is different, so that's why… I have make a change in the jQuery code, that should make it work with your html structure, just  as you expect.

Comment: Many thanks for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

My answer on this thread was working nice in WooCommerce 3 on Storefront theme…

Try instead this revisited code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'custom_template_single_price', 1 );
function custom_template_single_price(){
    if ( ! is_product() ) return; // Only on single product pages

    global $product, $post;

    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        // removing the price of variable products
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

        // Change location of
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_template_single_price', 10 );
    }
}

function replace_template_single_price(){
    global $product;

    // Main Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
    $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    // Sale Price
    $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
    sort( $prices );
    $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

    if ( $price !== $saleprice && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</del> <ins>' . $price . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</ins>';
    }

    ?>
    <style>
        div.woocommerce-variation-price,
        div.woocommerce-variation-availability,
        div.hidden-variable-price {
            height: 0px !important;
            overflow:hidden;
            position:relative;
            line-height: 0px !important;
            font-size: 0% !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('select').blur( function(){
            if( '' != $('input.variation_id').val() ){
                if($('p.availability'))
                    $('p.availability').remove();
                if($('p.stock'))
                    $('p.stock').remove();
                $('p.price').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html()).append('<p class="availability">'+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+'</p>');
            } else {
                $('p.price').html($('div.hidden-variable-price').html());
                if($('p.availability'))
                    $('p.availability').remove();
                if($('p.stock'))
                    $('p.stock').remove();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php

    echo '<p class="price">'.$price.'</p>
    <div class="hidden-variable-price" >'.$price.'</div>';
}
```

Tested in WooCommerce 3.2.x and works *(on storefront theme)*

I have **added some jQuery code to remove the stock availability label before setting it**. It should work for you too.

> For some themes with customizations on the html structure and classes names, you will need to make some changes in the code