# Woocommerce product price duplicating

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I want to add two prices on single product, first simple price was showing but when clicking on cariation size, price was duplicating, simple and variation both price showing, I want to show one price at a time.

[image: please see the image]

Comment: **This require to use jQuery**… But as you are using a custom plugin (or some customizations) to display sizes as swatches, you will need to adapt the code from this answer to make it work for you: [Replace the Variable Price range by the chosen variation price in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44914240/3730754)

Answer (score 1):

Fix 2x price
GoTo: www.YOURDOMAIN/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=tax
then remove {price_excluding_tax} from "Price display suffix" input field

Answer (score 0):

You Can try with jquery onchange function and get above product price and show at bottom

Comment: I have checked that also I put the if else statement, but it was not working on variation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this code. Hope it will work.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wp1232_remove_price_for_variations', 99 );

function wp1232_remove_price_for_variations() {
   global $product;

   if ( 'variable' == $product->get_type() ) {
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
   }
}
```

Comment: I add this code to my function.php file but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you try one time to change this action `add_action( 'init', 'wp1232_remove_price_for_variations', 99 );` to `add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wp1232_remove_price_for_variations', 9 );`

Comment: somethingndid work but there is still a problem, that by default no price was showing up. And when I am clicking on variation then the price will show up.

Comment: is there any way to dislay the normal price by default please.